# ffmpeg/ffprobe get last (few) frame info with show_frames

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am currently experimenting with ffmpeg and ffprobe.

I basically want to get info of last frame from "show_frames" but "show_frames" prints ALL the frames.

is there any way to filter this?

Answer (score 0):

No, ffprobe cannot do this for you (as far as I know). I had experimented with something similar in the past and was unable to find a solution using only ffprobe.

As a possible work around you may want to perform post-processing on the output.